# draw curve by equation

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to draw a line by equation ( a function in a drawing package ). The line should resemble a contour of a steel forged pressure vessel head.

The desired line shape:

[image: Pr.VesslHeadShape]

All black lines/arcs are tangent to each other

There are some user inputs:

D = inside diameter ( transformed to radius D/2 )

t = material thickness ( in sketch of the shape there is no thickness )

ht = straight length parallel to vessel axis

How were the derived parameters  calculated according the manufacturer?

r = `0,171875*(D + 2*t)`

R = `0,9*(D + 2*t)`

Comment: In your work, you need to show what is equated at the spherical / toro-spherical joint. (Downvote not mine).

Comment: Well, to be honest i'm not that good in math and don't know what you mean by that. Could you please explain?

Comment: Is it ASME code? That is maybe a specification.  I added a construction. Hope alright.

Comment: It could be ASME code or EN, is there difference in the transition? In my opinion there is not the transition should always be tangent. I know there is a difference in radius calculation.

Comment: It is compulsory to have a common slope and different curvature at transition. Learn things at  first, form opinions later on.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring thickness, draw angle $23.6^0$ for arc upto transition point T and then  continuation to center.

HINT

Draw 2 circles

$$ (x-MF )^2 + (y-0 )^2 = TF ^2 \,; (x- 0)^2 + (y+MO )^2 = TO^2 $$

and verify tangency at $T$.

Comment: I need a equation to use the program draw a line by equation. I can draw the correct shape it's not a problem but it gives me 2 arcs and when using equation line It is only 1 curve.

Comment: Can you not make it a conditional equation? If $\theta < 66.4^0$ then $ x=..,y=...;  $